# Issue while loading the data in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

I'm developing a asp.net application using twitter bootstrap.

I'm trying create a jqgrid.
While loading the data im facing issues. I'm getting an error **XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:....**

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  jQuery("#grid-container").jqGrid({
                    url: "test.url",
                    datatype: 'json',
                    mtype: 'POST',                                      
                    colNames: ['Id', 'Text', 'Name'],
                    colModel: [
                    { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', hidden: false, editable: true },
                     { name: 'Text', index: 'Text', hidden: false, editable: true },
                      { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', hidden: false, editable: true }
                    ],
                    jsonReader: {
                        id: 'Id',
                        repeatitems: false
                    },
                    height: "100%",
                    pager: '#grid-pager',
                    rowNum: 10,
                    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                    sortname: 'Id',
                    sortorder: 'desc',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    caption: "Risk Register",
                    loadComplete: function () {                       
                        var table = this;                       
                    }                  
                });
});
```

I found that data from dal is not converting into json type.. I'm not getting the response while debugging.

Please help me out.

Comment: ,did u returned the response as json in sever side?

Comment: yes. i have returned in handler function.

Comment: post your server side data.